# Model designer issue, QGIS 3.14 on iMAC

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I tried to make Model in Model designer but I don't see my new fields in designer window, but only the offer of the existing layers.

What's wrong and what did I miss?

There is no connection lines.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it qgis issue on imac or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select an input from your model, you must select `Add Model Input` to the left of the field where you select the input. See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380854/88814