# Changing inputs in QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis-modeler

I'm new to using the modeler function in QGIS.  I'm trying to follow the tutorial in the screenshot.  But when I follow the steps it ends up with my in/out algorithm not connected to the "counties layer/county name attribute" input with arrows.

How do I connect all these together?

[image: My screenshot]

[image: Tutorial]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double click on Extract Nueces County and define the counties layer as input. Maybe you can add a screenshot of the dialog window that opens when double clicking Extract Nueces County when you are unsure where and how to define the input.

Be sure you select `Add Model Input` to be able to select an input layer defined in your model:

[image]

If you have other inputs like for an attribute, select again for each input the button to the right to `Add Model Input`

[image]

Comment: Ok, I fixed it so an arrow is drawn from "Counties Layer" into the algorithm.  But there should also be another arrow from "County Name Attribute" also going to it.  Under "input layer" it only gives my the option to choose "Counties Layer" and not "County Name Attribute," even though it is clearly there.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pf39AcyFrAIYN2ufVN5DCtyWBlY0R3I9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Again, here as well: you sould select the `Add Model Input` button if you want to add the attribute you created in the model as an input. Consider it kind of a variable: when you run the model, you can define what attribute you want to use for the algorithm. What you did now: you selected an attribute from a layer in your project, not the input ("variable") you created in the model.

Comment: Important is not so much to have a connecting arrow in the model, but to understand what you want to do. In your last screenshot (linked to g-drive), you just filled a field that has a pre-defined value, not an input from the model you created.

Comment: I still don't understand.  Why can I only use "counties layer" as input and not "county name attribute?"

Comment: Added to reply for this question to my answer